# Как Вы храните дату и время в MSSQL Server либо PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, datetime, timestamp, unixtimestamp

Какой тип данных Вы используете- DATETIME With TimeZone или TimeStump?
Но автоматической генерации TimeStump в СУБД нет и нужно писать функцию.
На сколько быстро работает преобразование и в каком виде вообще сохранять дату и время, если сайт интернациональный?

Comment: В MS SQL есть тип `datetimeoffset`, для хранения значений `DateTimeOffset` из .NET достаточно точности `datetimeoffset(7)`.

Comment: UTC *(7 символов нужно...)*

Comment: @Igor то-есть можно тип DateTime и сохранять в дефолтное значение SYSUTCDATETIME() . И пользователю отправляется в формате дата время с учётом нулевой поправки времени. А у него сейчас зона, например, +2 -тогда у него должно быть время на 2 часа больше. Вообщем в этом суть, что б такое сделать